# limit one area and browse other people are using the same app

Tags: android

When my app  is triggered, it takes the current position of the user through the GPS (this function already implemented).

My question is: I want to know for example if I have users who are using my app in a given radius (1km for example). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need a server as well. Broadly speaking, the process is as follows:

- The app gets the location from Android.
- The app queries the server, sending the current location in its request.
- The server stores the location and the user name in a *spatial database*; that is, a database of users that can be indexed by location. It overwrites the previous location if there was one. The server should also store the time the location was set.
- The server also looks up the location in the spatial database to find all the users in the given radius, or the nearest *n* users. It sends the list of users back to the app. It might use JSON, XML, or some other format to send these data. (Since you control both the server and the app, you can choose whatever format you like.)
- The app reports its position to the server again if the device's location changes, and gets a new list of users.
- You can also use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html), or a persistent connection, to let the server notify the app when new users appear nearby, if your application needs that.
- When the user goes offline, the app sends another message to the server to tell it. This erases the user's location for the database so this user won't show up after he has left the area.
- The server should also delete locations from the database if they haven't been updated in a certain amount of time, in case the app crashed or got disconnected abruptly.

For the server, you can implement something on top of [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/), for example. PostGIS is a plugin for PostgreSQL that allows it to answer spatial queries.

This is a very specific need, so I don't think there's any existing code you can download to do this for you. Once you've tried it out, ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: then I will have my smartphone connected to the internet all the timeSo it works like this:
Every time I open the application, it sends to the server my latitude and longitude. Can I make an if statement to compare if the user already exists in the database, if it exists it will only update the latitude and longitude. correct?
If you have someone near the person, the server sends a list of other people who are close to her.
To use this shipping I use JSON?
Do you have any examples of this tool Google Cloud Messaging?
or some such tool PostGIS?
Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify these points, and with a link to the documentation for Google Cloud Messaging, which has downloadable demo code.

Comment: but how do I define this in 1km radius server?

Comment: It's a parameter of the SQL query you give to PostGIS. Take a look at the documentation.